# Заменить в вещественной матрице все отрицательные числа нулями

Tags: c, pascal, матрицы

мне необходимо заменить в вещественной матрице все отрицательные числа нулями, она должна храниться в текстовом файле. Я соображаю как это сделать на паскале, но в си я новичок.

```
//для создания
Var f:file of integer;
    i,n,m:integer;
Begin
    Randomize;
    write('Введите кол-во элементов: ');readln(n);
    Assign(f,'in.dat');Rewrite(f);
    For i:=1 to n do
     Begin
      m:=Random(101)-50;
      write(f,m);
     End;
    Close(f);
    writeln('Файл создан');
    readln;
End.
```

```
//для преобразования
Var f:file of integer;
    m,i:integer;
Begin
    Assign(f,'in.dat');Reset(f);
    i:=0;
    writeln('Исходный файл');
    While not Eof(f) do
     Begin
      read(f,m);
      write(m,' ');
     End;
    writeln;
    Reset(f);
    While not Eof(f) do 
     Begin
      read(f,m);
      if m<0 then
       Begin
        Seek(f,i);
        write(f,0);
       End;
      inc(i);
     End;
    Reset(f);
    writeln('Полученный файл');
    While not Eof(f) do
     Begin
      read(f,m);
      write(m,' ');
     End;
    readln;
End.
```